# Allowing specific people to view a github html site

Tags: html, authentication, ip, html-helper

How to allow specific people in your HTML site withouth Login?
Im trying to do a site that only allows friends in my school to view my site. The persons that are not allowed will only see a white screen.
Mostly because im doing a github site and i dont know how to do a login page. But when i tried to do a site that only allows specific IP's, i didn't know how to do it either...Can someone help me please?
PS: My school uses the same chromebooks.

I tried to do a IP's only but then noticed that the school wifi is the same IP...

Comment: this is not possible, any front end JS solution is insecure since the code is visible and editable by everyone. With just JS alone it's not possile. GitHub Pages doesn't allow you to use any server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github Pages does not support any server-side logic. You cannot use IP based authentication with it. You cannot do any kind of login feature with it.

The closest you could come would be to encrypt the contents of the documents using an algorithm that could only be decrypted with a specific secret. Then write JavaScript to prompt the user for that secret and use it to decrypt the payload and modify the DOM with it.

Then you'd need to distribute the secret among all the people who should have access to it.

This wouldn't be a good approach since it requires sharing the secret (violating the first rule of responsible password security).

It probably violates your "without login" restriction too.

Comment: But what students are doing is that i make them a site and they share it...i want to do a site that only allows like specific devices...i dont know if thats possible...and can i add a sign-in button?

Comment: Repeating your desire isn’t going to make it possible.

Comment: Im sorry and thank you for answering my question. I appreciate it